# best way to keep a connection alive and available in java EE environment

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb, design-patterns

I have web service client that connects to a MS Exchange server. The initial connection time is very long for this system, around 30 sec. So i would like to open this initial connection as soon as I start my application server and then let stateless ejbs use this connection without having to reconnect to the MS Exchange server. My solution to this would be to create a singleton EJB that gets injected into the statless ejb's so that my connection is always open, how ever i'n not sure this will work because it seem as the singleton EJB can get garbage collected.

**So my qustion is this:** Is this the correct way to do it or should I use a different approach for this "service provider" problem? If its correct then what about the garbage collection of the singleton, can that be avoided so I don't from time to time need to do re-connections? Thanks for any feedback and thoughts!

Comment: The problem of a Singleton being garbage-collected exists only in older JVMs. Have you read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514425/best-way-to-keep-a-connection-alive-and-available-in-java-ee-environment that I posted in answer to the other question of yours?

Comment: As an 'exchange server' do you mean Microsoft Exchange?

Comment: @PiotrekDe Yes thats correct. Updated it now.

Comment: @perissf Yes I did, and that was a very helpfull answer but I still have some problems and it was because of the link to the singleton pattern that i realized that it might not be the best solution to use  a singleton ejb.

Comment: Maybe you can check out Resource Adapters. I have never used them but it appears that they are designed for your purpose http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipgl.html

Comment: Not sure I understand the garbage collection issue. It isn't legal for a container to allow an `@Singleton` EJB to be garbage collected while the application is running.  That would be a container bug.

Comment: @DavidBlevins if that is true then Singleton ejb will work great for me. I just wasn't sure if that was the case and if that was the way to go at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with a single connection to your exchange server, then store your connection in a static variable.  Wrap it in a class that provides the connection via a getter which will also check and auto-reconnect before returning the connection.